# Kotlin calbbackFlow catch operator not catching Exceptions

Tags: exception, kotlin-flow

I am working with callBack flow to observe a Firestore document. My flow needs to throw ResourceNotFoundException when the document being watched gets moved or deleted by some other person using the app. Below is my code for the flow

```
 fun observeDocument(collectionId: String, documentId: String) = callbackFlow {

    database.collection(collectionId).document(documentId)
        .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, firebaseFireStoreException ->

            if (firebaseFireStoreException != null)
                throw firebaseFireStoreException

            if (documentSnapshot == null || !documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                throw ResourceNotFoundException("")
            }

            try {
                offer(documentSnapshot.toObject(PrintOrder::class.java))
            } catch (e: Exception) {

            }
        }

    awaitClose { }

}
```

and I am collecting the above flow in the ViewModel by using the following code

```
 viewModelScope.launch {

       repository.observeDocument(collectionId, documentId)
           .catch {e->
               _loadedPrintOrder.value = LoadingStatus.Error(e)
           }
           .onStart {
               _loadedPrintOrder.value = LoadingStatus.Loading(application.getString(R.string.one_moment_please))
           }
           .collect {
               _loadedPrintOrder.value = LoadingStatus.Success(it!!)
           }
   }
```

Now, the problem is catch operator is not catching the exception thrown from the flow (ResourceNotFoundException). I have even tried wrapping the flow collection code inside a try-catch block. Even the try-catch block fails to catch the exception and the app crashes.

How can I catch the Exception which is thrown from the callBackFlow during collection of the flow?

Answer (score 0):

The `catch` operator [catches exceptions in the flow completion](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/catch.html). It will catch only if the flow completes normally or exceptionally. As you saw, it will never be thrown inside a flow builder. Moreover, your flow never completes since you are using `awaitClose` to keep him alive.

Since this builder uses a [Channel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-channel/index.html) under the hood, you can [`close`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/close.html?query=abstract%20fun%20close(cause:%20Throwable?%20=%20null):%20Boolean) it manually with non-null cause in order to complete the flow exceptionally:

```
abstract fun close(cause: Throwable? = null): Boolean
```

So you can use a `try/catch` inside the `callbackFlow` builder to close it manually as follows:

```
database.collection(collectionId)
    .document(documentId)
    .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, firebaseFireStoreException ->
        try {
            if (firebaseFireStoreException != null)
                throw firebaseFireStoreException

            if (documentSnapshot == null || !documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                throw ResourceNotFoundException("Oops!")
            }

            offer(documentSnapshot.toObject(PrintOrder::class.java))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            close(e) // close the flow with a non-null cause
        }
    }
```

With this, you should be able to catch exceptions as your `firebaseFireStoreException`, `ResourceNotFoundException` or any other one inside the `catch` operator because the flow is now completed exceptionally.